# ffmpeg - how to encode two videos of different orientation without producing freeze frames in linux?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg fails to merge two video of different orientation.
See my bug  [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10449)

Two videos - one horizontally and one vertically. Trying to merge them using ffmpeg produce freeze frames and "No start code is found." or "Error splitting the input into NAL units." or "Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input".

By changing "rotation" using ffmpeg, in metadata only, same results.

So what is the proper way to encode two videos of different orientation without producing freeze frames in linux?